# android LruCache real device

Tags: android, web-services, android-lru-cache

I'm trying to create android application using RestFull web services when using and use Lrucahe to save images all application works done but when install application on real device threw an exception : java.lang.noclassdeffounderror android.util.lrucache  my device target is 2.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need appcompat v4 to use LruCache to run on APIs bellow 12. Add the library and import the class using:

```
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html